# Android App Signature Key

Tags: android, android-facebook

I want to get the key-hash from signed signature of my Android App so that I can integrate facebook login in my android app. I have created the signed signature using AndroidTools-->Export Signed Application Package. How can I read the key generated in the signature file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

Try this link: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1. I found that using the Facebook method of getting a Hash Key did not always work as advertised. This link however, has a different method of getting the Hash Key and has pretty much always worked.

Solution 2:

That being said, I always found the simplest thing to do was, let the Facebook SDK tell you what your Hash Key is. This is by far more simpler and shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes.

Step 1: In your Facebook SDK, locate the Util.java class. In that, change this:

private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = false;
to:

private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = true;
Step 2: Create a new Signed APK, transfer to your device and install. If it is already installed, naturally, it will prompt.

Step 3: With your DDMS (Logcat) running and your device connected to the computer, run the application and keep looking for a key mismatch warning. That warning has the actual Hash Key. Copy that key, go to your Facebook Developer page and add the new key to the list.